# Xcode Swift button hidden

Tags: swift, uibutton, xcode6, hidden

I have two buttons in VC. Button1 and Button2.

I also have one string variable "buttonToHide".
With some logic, I am finding the button to hide and hence buttonToHide = "Button2"

Now I want to hide that actual Button2 using the string var buttonToHide. How do I do that?

Button2.hidden = true is great but I need to use string to do that functionality.

Thanks very much !!

```
 @IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!

var ArrayHere = ["1","2","3","4"]

        var noEmptyStrings = ArrayHere.filter({$0 != "\(self.CorrectAnswer)"})

        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(noEmptyStrings.count)))

        var noEmptyStrings1 = noEmptyStrings.filter({$0 != "\(noEmptyStrings[randomIndex])"})


        var firstValue = "Button" + noEmptyStrings1.first!
        var lastvalue = noEmptyStrings1.last

        println("\(firstValue)")
        println("\(lastvalue)")

        firstValue.hidden = true  //THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Please be more specific and post some code. So you want to do the same function to multiple buttons?

Comment: Sorry I though I was very specific. Which part of the question needs more clarification? so basically I have 5 buttons. I want to disable 1 button and that button's name is stored in a string called "buttonToHide" via some validations. and now I want buttonToHide.hidden = true      but buttonToHide is String. so its not working as it is. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to store 2 buttons names in 2 different strings? Tell us something you want to reach.

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: and you do no want to use a switch/ifelse cascade?

Comment: How can I use switch in this case? All I am trying to achieve is to hide a button from a string.

Comment: ```func getMyButton(name:String) -> UIButton {if name == "Button1" {return Button1} else ...  }```

Comment: @ChristianDietrich: error: missing return in a function expected to return 'UIButton'

Comment: of course you have to make this complete ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than maintaining arrays and dealing with outlet collections, you might consider using `tag`s, an admittedly somewhat quaint but nevertheless intriguingly simple mechanism.

Give your buttons these tags in Interface Builder, e.g. 1 to 4. They will allow you to access these buttons easily.

Then you do not need a string to store the button to hide, just an `Int`. The following will hide the button to be hidden and unhide all other buttons.

```
for i in 1...4 {
   let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
   button.hidden = i == toHide
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store your buttons in an Array of Buttons. For example:

```
var myButtons = [UIButton]()
```

So you are able to filter Buttons for properties (to get the correct button, or use the key of array)

For example:

```
myButtons[1].hidden = true
```

Comment: That sounds like a great answer but how do I connect all buttons (1-4) from VC to storyboard if they are in array ?

Comment: You could create an outlet collection: @IBOutlet var collectionOfYourButtons: Array<UIButton>?  - and then drag every button to this collection.

Comment: Another idea is to use 4 different tags - on ViewDidLoad get all Buttons with your specific tags and insert them into an Array of Buttons

Comment: So your Collection/Array is not type if UIButtons.